# My Excel Macro fails with a runtime error: 1004 but only if other Office Applications are open

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a VBA Macro that pastes a chart as a picture onto a sheet. The code looks like this:

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chart_Number).Chart.CopyPicture`
    Appearance:=xlPrinted, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture

    Sheets(LName & " EMA1").Select
    Range("A" & Final_Position).Select
    If Chart_Number > 1 Then
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=ActiveCell
    End If

    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False _
        , DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

I know that you will chastise me for using ActiveSheet and Select... I am ready. I have tried other methods but can't seem to get around it. I would welcome suggestions, but I digress...

The error received at the ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial line is Run-time error: '1004' We couldn't paste this data because it took too long. Try reducing the size of the selection. If you're copying from a remote computer, your network performance may be the cause.

The interesting thing is that Windows 10 computers do not get the error and not all of our Windows 11 computers get it. However, it is consistent on the ones that do and I cannot get past it.

The workaround is to close all other Office applications, Word, PowerPoint and Outlook and then everything is just fine... no errors. I can do it programmatically when the Excel file is opened and then reopen the applications when it closes, but that is just a little on the clunky side.

If anyone has experienced this and can think of a solution, I am willing to try it. Thank you.

I tried the code below but kept getting a file not found error.

```
Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
Dim destinationRange As Range
Dim destinationShape As Shape

Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(LNAME & " EMA1") 
Set destinationRange = destinationSheet.Range("A" & Final_Position") 
Set destinationShape = destinationSheet.Shapes.AddPicture("", False, True, destinationRange.Left,   
    destinationRange.Top, destinationRange.Width, destinationRange.Height)`
```

Comment: Where and when do you run the code? Is it a service or web application?

Comment: The code generates internal reports. The application resides on SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using declared specific objects.

EDIT 1:

Try emptying the clipboard before the copy operation

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Macro:

```
Sub copyPasteChartEMF()

    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Empty the clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ' Copy the chart
    sourceSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlPrinted, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
        
    Dim destinationSheet As Worksheet
    Set destinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    Dim destinationRange As Range
    Set destinationRange = destinationSheet.Range("A1")
    
    ' Paste special the chart
    destinationSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Picture (Enhanced Metafile)", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried using the declared specific objects as suggested but received Run-Time Error: '1004' Method PasteSpecial of object '_Worksheef' failed. When I changed it to just destinationRange.PasteSpecial with no qualifiers, it ran fine on my Windows 10 machines but failed again on the Windows 11 machines with exactly the same error: Run-time error: '1004' We couldn't paste this data because it took too long. Try reducing the size of the selection. If you're copying from a remote computer, your network performance may be the cause.

Comment: And you're working on the same machine, right? I'm not using W11, unfortunately, so I cannot test it

Comment: Yes, I am working on the same machines but... I have some Windows 11 machines that are working just fine. It is so perplexing.

Comment: If it's memory problems, try emptying the clipboard. See my edit. Are you using 32 or 64 bit office version?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that all automated Office applications are run under the same security context on Windows. So, if you run any of the automated applications with admin privileges (`Run as Administartor`) you need to run both in the same way to be able to connect them using automation.

To put it simply, a security context is a bit of cached data about a user, including her SID, group SIDs, privileges, and some other stuff. One of the fundamental tenets of Windows security is that each process runs on behalf of a user, so each process has a security context associated with it, like a global variable controlled by the kernel. This allows the system to audit the actions taken by a process and make access control decisions when the process acquires resources.

Comment: All of the Office applications are run under the same security context. There is no difference on the machines that experience the failure versus the ones that don't.

Comment: Are they run on the server?